# How to install Webapp Manager in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

How to install Linux Mint's Webapp Manager app in Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Linux Mint's Web App Manager app in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads/ # You can find the file that you downloaded in ~/Downloads
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/linuxmint-packages/pool/main/w/webapp-manager/webapp-manager_1.3.4_all.deb  
sudo apt install ./webapp-manager_1.3.4_all.deb
```

This way of installing Web App Manager doesn't mess with your software sources. The downside of this is that if you install Web App Manager app this way it won't be automatically updated. The choice is yours because you can add Linux Mint repository and receive software updates (for Web App Manager only) by following the instructions in [How to Install Linux Mint’s Web App Manager in Ubuntu 20.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/install-linux-mints-web-app-manager-ubuntu-20-04/).

Comment: I updated my answer. It still works with the newer package.

Comment: Should switch to https mirror for safety

Comment: Here's a nice mirror link: https://mirrors.kernel.org/linuxmint-packages/pool/main/w/webapp-manager/webapp-manager_1.3.4_all.deb

Comment: It's a good link. The checksum hash is the same hexadecimal number for both of the .deb files.